# Undocumented switches for `date` command

Tags: linux, command-line

I use `date -I` all the time to make quick backups of things that I want dated.  I was looking to answer this question: [Linux Script- Date Manipulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306289/linux-script-date-manipulations) and found that I couldn't find `date`'s `-I` switch documented anywhere.

Does `date` have other magical powers that you find useful?  Where did you find out about them?

Comment: `man date` shows it on my machine. Doesn't it on yours?

Comment: @NiklasB. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=man%20date

Comment: Note: if it's undocumented, don't rely on it, for it *will* break at the least opportune moment. On my computer, `date -I` gives the same output as `date +%Y-%m-%d`; one of these is fully documented, the other not at all. I'd recommend the latter without any hesitation, for the documentation on what it does is completely clear. The former ... well, a side effect could be waking Cthulhu from his sleep in R'Lyeh for all we know ;) If there is an equivalent, documented way, avoid undocumented features.

Comment: @Piskvor: It'd be okay for me to ignore the compatibility concern for my personal backup scripts, but I sure won't take the risk of waking Cthulhu. Convinced.

Comment: (As far as more mundane reasons go: I've had an undocumented-but-widely-known feature blow up in my face when it went missing **in a minor upgrade** - the developers' rationale being "it's undocumented anyway, so anyone using it gets what they had coming")

Comment: @Piskvor: It depends on how it works, why it works, what it does and what are your goals, right? Say, if that for certain wakes up Cthulhu and that's what I want, I definitely should use it. No?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: My point exactly - but if it's undocumented, it's really hard to tell whether it wakes up Cthulhu every time or just in this specific version; whether by design or just as a side effect; and whether it wakes him dependably or just pokes him with a pointy stick :)