# Auto-update the date in a bash script

Tags: bash, sed, grep, sh

I have written a quick and trivial script that counts the number of times a particular section in my web page is clicked on a monthly basis, as follows:

```
cat logfile.2014-06*.log | grep -c -w -o 'somestring' >> clicks-201406.txt
echo " *** Number of clicks June 2014 - *** "
```

I would like to be able to automatically counts all clicks from the previous month, without amending the script itself. For example, by running the script in August 2014, only clicks from July 2014 are gathered. Can this be done in any way?

My log directory includes HTTP requests files created daily. For example:

```
logfile.2014-06-01.log
logfile.2014-06-02.log
logfile.2014-06-03.log
```

etc..

Thanks,

I.

Comment: Have a look at `Google Analytics` and you can do so much more measurement and analysis for very little effort in instrumenting your code.

Comment: Or indeed one of a myriad of opensource, free or commercial log-reporting packages if you don't want to change your web page code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `date`. It can be used to print dates other than the current one - see [Linux Script- Date Manipulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306289/linux-script-date-manipulations) (changing days rather than months, but the approach is the same)

```
`date --date="last month" +%Y-%m`
```

would give you (at the time of writing) "2014-07"